# Black Screen after grub - Ubuntu Server 14.04.4

Tags: boot, server, grub2, uefi

I have a Fit-PC3 ([specs here](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/specifications/fit-pc3-models/?model[]=fit-PC3-T56N-D2x2-WB-H320-XLM-FM4U)), but when I want to install Ubuntu Server (by choosing the first option given on the grub menu), a black screen appears only.

I know this is a common issue, and I know I have to edit some things in the commands before the boot, but nothing changed.

So, here's what I did :

- `nomodeset` on the boot command (after `quiet`) -> Nothing
- `acpi=off` on the boot command (after `quiet`) -> Nothing
- Both of them -> Nothing
- Disabled EFI mode ( = not even boots the USB drive) -> Nothing

Is there anything I forgot ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I feel like a real noob right now.

I was using Unetbootin on OS X. I think it was not doing a good job for my USB key.
So I used Linux Live USB Creator on Windows, and it work great. No command to configure on the grub options.

:)

Comment: Just to be sure, did you successfully installed "Ubuntu Server 14.04" on Fit-PC3 computer? Is it also support "Ubuntu Desktop 14.04"?